# C#-comparing combobox and that of the list items

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, itext

I have a combobox in which i can select three items  and a list that contains items i want to check first of all whether the value selected from the combobox is in list and then the list item which is same as combobox one ; want to do some ops on it.

```
List<string>names = af.GetBlankSignatureNames();
comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();//combobox value taken
```

How to do so?

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
if(names.Any(r=> r == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
{
     // match found
}
else
{
    // not found
}
```

Or to get the item from the list try:

```
string str = names.FirstOrDefault(r=> r == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

if `str` is null that means string not found in the `names` list, if its not null then you got the string as well, *(which by the way would be same as `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`)*